# How do I allow two concurrent processes to communicate?

Tags: c, perl, pipe

I have two separate processes: a C program that outputs comma separated values followed by a newline every second, and a Perl program that accepts data (in the same format) and processes this data.

The C program outputs (via printf) values as such:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12  
...
```

The Perl program sits in an infinite loop waiting on a line basis for STDIN in order to process this data:

```
while ($line = <STDIN>)
{
    chomp($line) # Line should now read "1,2,3,4,5,6"
    # Process data
}
```

I want these two processes to communicate in real time.  Standard bash pipes do not work (e.g. process1 | process2) because the Perl program waits for the first program to finish before processing the input.

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions, or insightd as to a solution to this problem?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: strictly speaking, this has nothing to do with "real time"

Comment: You're absolutely right, I wrote this in a rush and couldn't think of a better way to explain how I wanted these processes to work.  Concurrent may have been a better choice.

Comment: Concurrent is much better, and there is an edit button for you to fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pipes should be fine for this; you just need to control when the output of your C program is flushed to make it available to the perl script incrementally.  You can do this in the C program using [`fflush()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fflush.html), which will force the buffer from your C program to be pushed out so the perl program can read it.

There is nothing inherent about pipes that would cause the perl program to wait for the C program to finish writing before processing its output.  Your perl program is written so that it processes `STDIN` one line at a time:

```
while ($line = <STDIN>) { ... }
```

`<>` in this context reads one line from `STDIN`, but if there's not one available it will block until one is.  A call to `fflush()` from the C program will make this happen.

Take a look at the [Wikipedia article on Pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)#Implementation).  The implementation section gives a brief description of how pipes are buffered, which should help you understand how your processes communicate.  Pipes **do** allow concurrency between processes, and processes reading from and writing to pipes are managed by the scheduler just like other processes.  Your problem here is with the buffering.

Comment: I thought C programs flushed all output whenever they printed a newline.

Comment: You were right on with this answer -- I had even explored fflush but I never thought to use it on stdout.  And due to the nature of the perl program's behavior, I had mistook it for 'waiting' on the c program.  I added fflush(stdout) after my printf statements and it worked flawlessly! Thanks!!

Comment: @Chris Lutz, the automatic flush only happens if the stream is in line buffered mode, which is usually only true if the stream is open on a tty. Once stdout is a pipe, it defaults to fully buffered for best performance.

Answer (score 5):

The C program should fflush() its output buffers explictly, or use a pty.  The latter is much more awkward but keeps the C code simpler.  Try "man 3 fflush" if this is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: Using a pty is overkill; flushing the output is important if using stdio in the C code (and not material if using write() directly).

Comment: A pty is only necessary if the two processes must interact, and then really only if one or both must be oblivious to having a non-human as the interacting party. Ptys are also not very portable outside of unix-like platforms.

Comment: I agree that pty is overkill, but it tricks the C program to autoflush after every newline.  In that sense (and in that sense alone!) it makes the C program simpler at the expense of a more complicated environment.